# Footer separated from other content

Tags: html, css, margin, footer

So i dont have set margines on section before footer but somehow it is separated and i cant seem to find out why. Any idea? thanks!

html:

```
<section>
<div class="content"></div>
</section>

<footer>
<div id="footer"></div>
</footer>
```

and css:

```
.content{
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(135,127,127) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(135,127,127) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(135,127,127) 0%, rgb(37,37,35)        69%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(135,127,127) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(135,127,127) 0%, rgb(37,37,35) 69%);

 background-image: -webkit-gradient(
linear,
left bottom,
left top,
color-stop(0, rgb(135,127,127)),
color-stop(0.69, rgb(37,37,35))
```

);

```
 #footer{
  background:url(images/footer.png) left top no-repeat;
  height:450px;
   }
```

Comment: Can you show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying a CSS Reset before you do any of your styling: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

In HTML4 specs (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) there is a default stylesheet defining margins and other formatting. It can cause that the browser renders margin even though you didn't write it in your CSS.

As far as I know, there is no specs for a default stylesheet in HTML5 yet, thus the browsers use their own default stylesheets.

Therefore, it seems that the margin used by `section` element has some margin set by default (in the browser). The best way how to avoid this is to reset CSS.

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/ is probably a good solution for you.